# Optional series in a SSRS chart?

Tags: reporting-services, charts, series, option-type

is it possible to make a series in a chart optional (i.e. only rendered when the user clicks a checkbox, in case the corresponding query takes a while and may not be required)?

Or are there any alternative solutions where users can incrementally select the data series/charts they would like to see?

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem in SSRS 2008, I was trying to hide a series based on the value of the series value. I tried to set the visibility on the series, but that did nothing. Then I tried hiding the series on legend hoping it would also hide it on the chart, it did not. Finally, I set the value of the series to an expression, `=iif(fieldvalue=0,"",fieldvalue)`, so it would return no value for the series if it had a value of 0, it also hides the series in the legend. This is a little late, but hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with Parameters.

You can set parameters to decide what is to be displayed on the report during runtime.  You can programatically set the parameters with the help of a few controls places alongside the reportviewer control.